# Geth not updating blocks after restart

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

Previously my geth node was working totally fine but due to some reason I had to restart the node. so I followed this commands: `sudo kill -INT <GETH_PID>`. Then restarted it with the folowing command:

`nohup geth  --syncmode "fast" --http --http.api "personal,eth,network,web3,net,db" --ipcpath "/home/ubuntu/ethereum/datadir//geth.ipc" --cache=20480 --ws  --ws.api "personal,eth,network,web3,net,db" --ws.origins "*" &`

but after restarting geth node is stuck at previously synced block `12964999` and its not updating to latest block. and eth.syncing is returning false.

Below is log after restarting geth node:

```
INFO [08-06|15:14:26.349] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [08-06|15:14:26.350] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
WARN [08-06|15:14:26.621] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=20480 updated=10705
INFO [08-06|15:14:26.622] Set global gas cap                       cap=25,000,000
INFO [08-06|15:14:26.624] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=1.57GiB dirty=2.61GiB
INFO [08-06|15:14:26.624] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=5.23GiB handles=524,288
INFO [08-06|15:14:28.550] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [08-06|15:14:28.610] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: 7280000 Petersburg: 7280000 Istanbul: 9069000, Muir Glacier: 9200000, Berlin: 12244000, YOLO v3: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [08-06|15:14:29.244] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [08-06|15:14:29.244] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/ubuntu/.ethash               count=2
INFO [08-06|15:14:29.250] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1 dbversion=8
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.282] Loaded most recent local header          number=12,964,999 hash=3de6bb..31a633 td=28,494,401,598,154,452,845,073 age=1d2h41m
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.283] Loaded most recent local full block      number=12,964,999 hash=3de6bb..31a633 td=28,494,401,598,154,452,845,073 age=1d2h41m
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.283] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=12,964,999 hash=3de6bb..31a633 td=28,494,401,598,154,452,845,073 age=1d2h41m
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.284] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=12,684,308
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.471] Setting new local account                address=<MY_COINBASE_ADDR>
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.476] Setting new local account                address=<MY_COINBASE_ADDR>
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.476] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=3 dropped=0
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.476] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.476] Switch sync mode from fast sync to full sync 
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-15T05:24:17+0000 age=1mo3w1d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-15T05:50:14+0000 age=1mo3w1d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-15T08:44:42+0000 age=1mo3w1d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-18T10:27:31+0000 age=1mo2w5d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-18T10:38:09+0000 age=1mo2w5d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-18T10:59:42+0000 age=1mo2w5d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-21T09:52:42+0000 age=1mo2w2d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-21T10:03:13+0000 age=1mo2w2d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-22T08:46:06+0000 age=1mo2w1d
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-07-26T07:22:57+0000 age=1w4d7h
WARN [08-06|15:14:36.482] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-08-06T10:46:09+0000 age=4h28m27s
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.482] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.3-stable-991384a7/linux-amd64/go1.16.3
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.605] New local node record                    seq=36 id=53383e050c0b85a7 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.606] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://1b4cab7215b58b107e44d534c32e9f24d06f750ecb1a692a9568e0c03a6195ccad3d83149bdb9c56f97fe53838813a121a7645fa8bc3528bf56cbbdebb6c46d7@127.0.0.1:30303
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.607] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth.ipc
ERROR[08-06|15:14:36.607] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable="[network db]" available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"
ERROR[08-06|15:14:36.608] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable="[network db]" available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.608] HTTP server started                      endpoint=[::]:8545 prefix= cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [08-06|15:14:36.608] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8546
INFO [08-06|15:14:42.930] New local node record                    seq=37 id=53383e050c0b85a7 ip=100.25.22.96 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [08-06|15:14:46.915] Looking for peers                        peercount=4 tried=14 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:14:49.948] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=cb5b9771 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
ERROR[08-06|15:14:54.550] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=57574a81 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:14:56.980] Looking for peers                        peercount=7 tried=30 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:15:07.109] Looking for peers                        peercount=9 tried=37 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:15:17.199] Looking for peers                        peercount=10 tried=36 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:15:27.276] Looking for peers                        peercount=10 tried=32 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:15:33.801] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=1d4fc8e3 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
ERROR[08-06|15:15:37.274] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=4a3bc9b0 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:15:37.282] Looking for peers                        peercount=12 tried=27 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:15:45.639] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=24f7f7bb err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:15:47.354] Looking for peers                        peercount=17 tried=28 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:15:57.524] Looking for peers                        peercount=17 tried=28 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:16:07.607] Looking for peers                        peercount=19 tried=37 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:16:17.608] Looking for peers                        peercount=20 tried=23 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:16:17.994] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=542efdfc err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:16:27.609] Looking for peers                        peercount=23 tried=32 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:16:37.615] Looking for peers                        peercount=25 tried=17 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:16:47.922] Looking for peers                        peercount=30 tried=41 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:17:00.779] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=2b187151 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
ERROR[08-06|15:17:02.256] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=b545eaf2 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:17:15.306] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x1A321811bcae819f5a63D246CBaE00c627Dfa218
ERROR[08-06|15:17:30.845] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=6d05d70a err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [08-06|15:22:46.246] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=99a6ef329a055876 conn=dyndial addr=34.121.180.224:30303 type=erigon/v2021.06.5-al...
ERROR[08-06|15:22:46.246] Ethereum peer removal failed             peer=99a6ef32 err="peer not registered"
ERROR[08-06|15:28:46.087] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=1d4fc8e3 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:35:08.387] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet... 
INFO [08-06|15:35:08.389] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [08-06|15:35:08.389] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
WARN [08-06|15:35:08.391] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=20480 updated=10705
INFO [08-06|15:35:08.392] Set global gas cap                       cap=25,000,000
INFO [08-06|15:35:08.393] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=1.57GiB dirty=2.61GiB
INFO [08-06|15:35:08.393] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=5.23GiB handles=524,288
INFO [08-06|15:35:10.191] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [08-06|15:35:10.192] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: 7280000 Petersburg: 7280000 Istanbul: 9069000, Muir Glacier: 9200000, Berlin: 12244000, YOLO v3: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [08-06|15:35:10.857] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [08-06|15:35:10.857] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/ubuntu/.ethash               count=2
INFO [08-06|15:35:10.858] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1 dbversion=8
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.124] Loaded most recent local header          number=12,964,999 hash=3de6bb..31a633 td=28,494,401,598,154,452,845,073 age=1d3h1m
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.124] Loaded most recent local full block      number=12,964,999 hash=3de6bb..31a633 td=28,494,401,598,154,452,845,073 age=1d3h1m
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.124] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=12,964,999 hash=3de6bb..31a633 td=28,494,401,598,154,452,845,073 age=1d3h1m
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.124] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=12,684,308
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.248] Setting new local account                address=0xbE2B90CcB7b0C56ffF49D8858a37E6Bfe2c4361e
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.249] Setting new local account                address=0x88104fA88993F96C7C8E7E69dd8C75c41Ff83bAa
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.249] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=3 dropped=0
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.249] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.249] Switch sync mode from fast sync to full sync 
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Old unclean shutdowns found              count=1
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-15T05:50:14+0000 age=1mo3w1d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-15T08:44:42+0000 age=1mo3w1d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-18T10:27:31+0000 age=1mo2w5d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-18T10:38:09+0000 age=1mo2w5d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-18T10:59:42+0000 age=1mo2w5d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-21T09:52:42+0000 age=1mo2w2d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-21T10:03:13+0000 age=1mo2w2d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-06-22T08:46:06+0000 age=1mo2w1d
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-07-26T07:22:57+0000 age=1w4d8h
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-08-06T10:46:09+0000 age=4h49m3s
WARN [08-06|15:35:12.250] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-08-06T15:14:36+0000 age=20m36s
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.250] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.3-stable-991384a7/linux-amd64/go1.16.3
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.296] New local node record                    seq=38 id=53383e050c0b85a7 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.297] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://1b4cab7215b58b107e44d534c32e9f24d06f750ecb1a692a9568e0c03a6195ccad3d83149bdb9c56f97fe53838813a121a7645fa8bc3528bf56cbbdebb6c46d7@127.0.0.1:30303
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.298] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/ubuntu/ethereum/datadir/geth.ipc
ERROR[08-06|15:35:12.298] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable="[network db]" available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"
ERROR[08-06|15:35:12.298] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable="[network db]" available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.299] HTTP server started                      endpoint=[::]:8545 prefix= cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [08-06|15:35:12.299] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8546
ERROR[08-06|15:35:12.959] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=6631e09d err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
ERROR[08-06|15:35:14.103] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=7072d8cb err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:35:15.869] New local node record                    seq=39 id=53383e050c0b85a7 ip=100.25.22.96 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [08-06|15:35:22.338] Looking for peers                        peercount=6 tried=27 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:35:25.537] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=f2746164 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:35:32.362] Looking for peers                        peercount=8 tried=21 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:35:42.471] Looking for peers                        peercount=8 tried=30 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:35:52.617] Looking for peers                        peercount=10 tried=35 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:35:53.129] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=ae373d45 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:36:02.949] Looking for peers                        peercount=11 tried=30 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:36:12.950] Looking for peers                        peercount=16 tried=31 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:36:18.351] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=9324937b err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:36:23.050] Looking for peers                        peercount=16 tried=43 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:36:33.296] Looking for peers                        peercount=18 tried=27 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:36:39.299] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=0be30b7e err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:36:43.299] Looking for peers                        peercount=19 tried=38 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:36:53.442] Looking for peers                        peercount=21 tried=35 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:37:03.540] Looking for peers                        peercount=24 tried=38 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:37:06.175] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=b53043e9 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:37:13.623] Looking for peers                        peercount=31 tried=35 static=0
WARN [08-06|15:37:19.108] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=40b120f8fde13baf conn=inbound addr=109.43.48.23:15105 type=Geth/v1.10.5-stable-...
ERROR[08-06|15:37:19.108] Ethereum peer removal failed             peer=40b120f8 err="peer not registered"
INFO [08-06|15:37:23.950] Looking for peers                        peercount=31 tried=34 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:37:26.960] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=050c2976 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|15:37:33.956] Looking for peers                        peercount=32 tried=39 static=0
INFO [08-06|15:37:43.995] Looking for peers                        peercount=32 tried=36 static=0
ERROR[08-06|15:39:28.940] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=9efe5e39 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
ERROR[08-06|16:13:09.222] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=f0534649 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|16:35:12.248] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|16:35:12.251] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|16:35:14.809] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=2.560s
INFO [08-06|17:35:12.248] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|17:35:12.261] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|17:35:15.855] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=3.598s
INFO [08-06|18:35:12.248] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|18:35:12.250] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|18:35:16.129] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=3.878s
ERROR[08-06|19:13:12.219] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=aa1d27f0 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|19:35:12.248] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|19:35:12.253] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|19:35:16.272] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=4.024s
INFO [08-06|20:35:12.248] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|20:35:12.251] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|20:35:16.319] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=4.069s
ERROR[08-06|21:28:36.381] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=5923554b err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [08-06|21:35:12.249] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|21:35:12.250] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|21:35:16.434] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=4.185s
INFO [08-06|22:35:12.248] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|22:35:12.250] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|22:35:16.518] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=4.269s
INFO [08-06|23:35:12.248] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [08-06|23:35:12.251] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=3 accounts=2
INFO [08-06|23:35:16.726] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth/triecache elapsed=4.477s
INFO [08-07|00:01:19.669] Etherbase automatically configured       address=<MY_COINBASE_ADDR>
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The block 12964999 is the last block you can download without upgrading to EIP 1559. After block 12_965_000 we have forked to a new feature list which you can find out on the internet for more details.

```
MainnetChainConfig = &ChainConfig{
    ChainID:             big.NewInt(1),
    ....
    LondonBlock:         big.NewInt(12_965_000),
    ....
}
```

you have to upgrade to `geth 1.10.6`

Comment: Thanks a lot. after updating geth is syncing now. :)